# Change children around in parent container component

Tags: angular

If I had components defined as:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'parent',
    template: `
        <div><ng-content></ng-content></div>
    `
})
export class Parent { ... }

@Component({
    selector: 'data',
    template: `
        <ng-content></ng-content>
    `
})
export class Data { ... }
```

And some markup such as:

```
<parent>
    <data>a</data>
    <data>b</data>
    <data>c</data>
</parent>
```

Is there any way to reorder the items via `parent's` controller such that they might eventually be rendered `c, a, b` (for example)? It's easy enough to have a collection of data items in javascript and `*ngFor` + some `| reorder-pipe` to do so. But I've found that maintainability suffers dramatically if I can't just see my data items declared statically.

Answer (score 1):

I found a way to do this when children are mapped into `<ng-content>` and then handling DOM elements directly. I would prefer a way to handle the `ComponentRef`s or `ViewRef`s instead.

```
@Component({
    selector: '[parent]',
    template: `
        <div #parent><ng-content></ng-content></div>
    `
})
export class Parent implements AfterViewInit {
    @ContentChildren(Data) datas: QueryList<Data>;
    @ViewChild('parent') parentDiv: any;

    ngAfterViewInit() {
        let el = this.parentDiv.nativeElement;

        // Collect children, append sort prop, and clean.
        let children = [];
        let datas = this.datas.toArray();
        for (let i = 0; i < datas.length; ++i) {
            children.push(el.removeChild(el.children[0]));
            children[i].dataset.sort = datas[i].sort;
        }

        // Sort and re-add.
        let sorted = children.sort(
            (x, y) => parseInt(x.dataset.sort) - parseInt(y.dataset.sort));
        for (let i of sorted) {
            el.insertBefore(i, null);
        }
    }
}

@Directive({
    selector: '[data]'
})
export class Data {
    @Input() sort: number;
}

<div parent>
   <div child sort="2">a</div>
   <div child sort="3">b</div>
   <div child sort="1">c</div>
</div>
```